# What is the difference between BSD format and RFC5424 format in logj 2?

Tags: java, log4j2

What is the difference between BSD format and RFC5424 format in logj 2?
What is the difference bteween Syslog Appender and Socket Appender in log4j 2?

Which is best among all?

Answer (score 1):

Have you read [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html)?

> The SyslogAppender is a SocketAppender that writes its output to a
> remote destination specified by a host and port in a format that
> conforms with either the BSD Syslog format or the RFC 5424 format. The
> data can be sent over either TCP or UDP.

Details about formats :

- BSD format [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3164).
- RFC5424 format [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424)